# Can we use Android studio for AOSP development?

Tags: java, android, ide, android-studio

Can we use `Android studio` for `AOSP`**(Android Open Source Project)** development, is there a way to do it. I didnt find one. anybody got any idea on this please ?

Comment: Import AOSP source to use in Android Studio or Eclipse, please find the full instructions here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/tools/idegen/README

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use Android Studio as a IDE for AOSP, since it's just a modified version of InteliJ's IDE.

from AOSP root:

```
 make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

Then just "Open Project" in Android Studio and select the android.ipr it generated.

Comment: Every time I'm trying to run this code I get java exception 

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.java (Is a directory)

Comment: Setting up Intellij with CyanogenMod/AOSP development - https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html

Comment: @Rosenpin You will need to modify `development/tools/idegen/src/Configuation.java` at line 135 to ensure the file is not a directory (`path.endsWith(".java") && !file.isDirectory()`).

Comment: If there is no idegen and if you prefer intellij, try to import project with intellij and 'gradle' for model. That worked for me.

Comment: Update: you need to run `source build/envsetup.sh && lunch` before run `make idegen`, as AOSP contains its own buildtools(javac, make etc)

Comment: I found https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/aosp-sources-in-the-ide-860 to be a good (and complete) HOWTO.

Answer (score 15):

To import AOSP source in Android Studio or Eclipse, follow the full instructions here :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/tools/idegen/README

Answer (score 2):

What Pedlar suggested above is one way of doing it. I ran into lot of Jar dependency issues when I tried it with IDEA community edition (Android Studio is a fork of IDEA IDE). The IDE keeps prompting you about duplicate jars etc. The generated project includes framework Java sources as well as App sources. I tried to build an App project which resulted in broken AOSP build. IMHO, IDEA is a great IDE for Java development. But didn't work well with AOSP.

What worked for me is using eclipse to browse/edit/debug framework sources, but build the code from a terminal window. To avoid AOSP build breaks, please create a shadow dir of AOSP (i.e. lndir of AOSP) and use shadow dir for eclipse project.

This is explained at [Using eclipse to browse/edit AOSP](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html) link in step by step.
If you are working on AOSP, you might want to check [Debugging Android framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html).

Comment: Then how to generate the apk for individual app?