# Failed to import AOSP code to IDEA / Intellij / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-source, android-5.0-lollipop

I downloaded and built the new android lollipop source code on my computer and tried importing the code into an IDE, I tried intellij and android studio using the post here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471652/3057931

I tried executing the  development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh file but seem to keep getting a java file error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.java (Is a directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
at Configuration.parsePackageName(Configuration.java:204)
at Configuration.rootOf(Configuration.java:180)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:140)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.traverse(Configuration.java:167)
at Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:72)
at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

This method worked for me in the KitKat source code but in this build I keep getting this error.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

I really really need to use intellij or android studio for the AOSP code.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: [This comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/qoNNNs9Vnns/bltPQJ4EBd8J) might help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I ran into this comment but I didn't quit understood what I should do..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`res.java` is a folder, but `idegen.jar` recognize it as a regular java code to parse, what is a bug.

So rename `./out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.java` to `./out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.j` can bypass this issue.

full steps as below:

1. `source build/envsetup.sh`
2. `lunch aosp_arm-eng`
3. `make`
4. `mmm development/tools/idegen/`
5. `mv out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.java out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.j`
6. `development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh`

now, `android.iml`, `android.ipr` and `.classpath` will be generated.

then, you can rename res.j back to res.java if you want.

the left is the same as you do before.

Comment: after `source build/envsetup.sh`, `mmm` will be available

Comment: I tried your updated answer and I am getting this error 

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/res.j/res.java (Is a directory)

Comment: Because the bug is a folder named *.java is parsed as a normal java source code file, so rename all folder name *.java to others, and re-run the idegen.sh will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this patch solved it for me
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/116243/