# Where is source code of ANRManagerNative located in aosp project

Tags: android, android-source, android-anr-dialog

I'm a new bee in AOSP project. I'm trying to find codes relevant to the ANR system. But when I search ANR in all sources, none was found. Where can I find the ANRManagerNative of other ANR classes, in java sources or c/c++ sources? Thanks.

Comment: grep for `inputDispatchingTimedOut`

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your comment. I have checked these codes, and found it send a timeout message out. I want to know where the message goes and how the ANR Dialog is finally pop out.

Comment: see the Handler definition where the Message is being sent

Answer (score 2):

In general, once you get the AOSP source tree into an Android Studio project, navigating the code becomes much easier. You can consult [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727607/can-we-use-android-studio-for-aosp-development).

I did a search for it in this fashion and found `<aosp-root>/system/extras/ANRdaemon/ANRdaemon.cpp`.

Comment: Currently (Summer 2022) this class is at https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/extras/ANRdaemon/ANRdaemon.cpp;l=1?q=ANRdaemon.cpp&sq=