# How to add system api classes to your android project for non AOSP builds

Tags: gradle, android-source

I have an android system app that is currently being built with the android build system. The SDK in use is system_current as it uses some system apis.

For external dependency reasons, ease of development, debugging etc, it would be nice to move this app to Android Studio and use Gradle to build.

Converting the sources to build with Gradle is straight forward enough.  However, at build time, the system APIs are not found as those are not available in the normal SDK.  I thought that by generating the SDK from the AOSP sources I'd get an SDK I could use, but that target output seems to also not have the System APIs available.

How would I change my gradle build to be able to use the System SDK to compile against?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways depending if you are only trying to use current non-public APIs, or of you've added custom ones yourselves and are trying to access those.

- If you're only trying to use current system-level APIs, you can use `android.jar` from this repository https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api
- If you have added some new method that isn't part of standard AOSP, then it's a but more work.
  The reason that all methods don't show as part of Android SDK is that in AOSP code they are annotated with `@hide`. This means that when SDK is generated, they are exlcuded.
  You'll need to remove that annotation for the methods that you want to use.  Then you'l need

  - Run `make update-api` to update the public API of the project.
  - Make the Android SDK from code by following: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt
  - Change the Android SDK path in Android Studio to use the custom one you build.

---

There's also the possibility of accessing methods via reflection on runtime without SDK generation. It's slower and messier to code though.

Comment: Turns out this was very close to the solution that worked for me.  I removed the @hide annotations and could build the updated api, but during the build for the Sdk there were link errors with documents.  It wasn't easy to figure out so I decided to go with just using the pre-modified jar dependency, which make it so I can build outside of the aosp tree, and probably is a better long term solution anyway.  Thanks for the input though I learned a bit more today.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand exactly what you mean by normal SDK etc.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/build

The key part is to have a

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

...

android {
   ...
}
```

If on the other hand you wanted to build with a desktop JDK but compile against java APIs you could add a dependency on robolectric and you can get a jar you can import into another Android project.

```
implementation "org.robolectric:android-all:11-robolectric-6757853"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The robolectric library gets me much closer to building.  I do have access to the whole AOSP source tree locally though. Is there a target in AOSP to build the dependency? I'm very close with using the robolectric for dependencies but there seem to be some classes that are not up to date in that library.  For instance, I'm getting an error on RecoverySystem.verifyPackageCompatibility.  There is a RecoverySystem class in the robolectric library but it doesn't have the verifyPackageCompatibility method.  My local AOSP sources do have that method though.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio isn't really designed to work with System APIs. Even if you make Gradle build your platform app, you will also need to sign it with the same certificate as your AOSP build (so that you could *run* it). As you noticed, if you decide to use Roboelectric you would also need to modify it yourself to match your current AOSP version (System APIs are not as stable as Public APIs and Roboelectric needs to constantly chase all the changes).

I would suggest to keep using the AOSP build system but optimize our workflow.

### Ease of development

Doing a full build/flash for every change in your component must be a pain. But if you are just modifying a single app, you can get away with just building that single component:

1. `~/aosp/ $ m -j` -- do a full build first
2. flash a clean image (with your platform certificate)
3. `~/aosp/path/to/your/app/ $ mma -j` -- build your app with all dependencies after you made changes
4. `$ adb root && adb remount && adb sync`

Basically, `adb sync` works great if you don't touch any APIs or parts of Android Framework (which would cause a rebuild of thousands other objects). If you see `adb sync` updating more than handful of files, you'll likely end up with a bad system and need to do a full flash.

### Debugging

While Android Studio is a to-go solution for regular apps, framework and the platform apps go with InteliJ (you can probably use Android Studio, but there won't be much of use of Android plugins on top InteliJ) plus some configuration (see idegen.sh - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727607/can-we-use-android-studio-for-aosp-development)).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I already have the app working with the aosp build so I'm familiar with those steps and the signing certificate.  The reason I want to switch to grade is for dependencies not managed by aosp (like firebase for example).  I guess if I can't get it to work I can alway add those dependencies manually instead.  I was thinking todays project will be to modify robolectric and see if that is the best path forward.

Comment: In this case modifying Roboelectric seems the way to go indeed. It's a good idea to push these changes to upstream, so that others can use it and you don't have to maintain it yourself.

Comment: So robolectric was a very close start with the android-all dependency.  I tried to see if I could easily modify it but it wasn't clear where to make the modification.  The android-hidden-api jar works though.

Comment: Did you actually need to sign the app with the platform key as @twasilczyk mentioned? I was able to build my apk with Android Studio, but when running on the emulator it doesn't  seem to run my system api call.